# .Net Core 3.1. Need Nested Group By item daily Quantity show

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, system.linq.dynamic

I want to nested group by . 
I take the order items weekly and group them by type name, then I want to collect the daily sales amount of the product with this type name and get the results as below.

But I am making a mistake in the `Linq` query I did and I couldn't solve the reason.

```
  return [
      {
        name: 'Shoes',
        data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268],
      },
      {
        name: 'Africa',
        data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766],
      },
      {
        name: 'tshirt',
        data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628],
      },
      {
        name: 'pants',
        data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201],
      },
      {
        name: 'Oceania',
        data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46],
      },
    ];
```

**My Code:**

```
   IReadOnlyList<OrderItemReportDto> query = await _context.OrderItems
                                    .GroupBy(x => new { x.ItemOrdered.ProductType })
                                         .Select(y => new OrderItemReportDto
                                         {
                                             Name = y.Key.ProductType,
                                             Quantity = y.Sum(c => c.Quantity),
                                             Count = y.GroupBy(x => x.CreatedTime.Date).Select(x => x.Sum(c => c.Quantity)).ToArray()
                                         })
                                         .ToListAsync();
        return query;
```

**OrderItemReportDto :**

```
   public class OrderItemReportDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int[] Count { get; set; }
    }

Order Items :
 

  public class OrderItem : BaseEntity
    {
        public OrderItem()
        {
        }

        public OrderItem(OrderProductItem ıtemOrdered, decimal price, int quantity)
        {
            ItemOrdered = ıtemOrdered;
            Price = price;
            Quantity = quantity;
            CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public OrderProductItem ItemOrdered { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedTime
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dateCreated.HasValue
                   ? this.dateCreated.Value
                   : DateTime.Now;
            }

            set { this.dateCreated = value; }
        }
        private DateTime? dateCreated = null;

    }
```

**but error is :**

```
{
    "StatusCode": 500,
    "Message": "The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:\r\nKeySelector: new { ProductType = (t.ItemOrdered_ProductType) }, \r\nElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: \r\n    EntityType: OrderItem\r\n    ValueBufferExpression: \r\n        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)\r\n    IsNullable: False\r\n)\r\n)\r\n    .GroupBy(x => x.CreatedTime.Date)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."
}
```

Comment: Seems, you have to load initial data into memory, then to calculate it. EF isn't able to translate nested group-by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `_context.OrderItems.GroupBy`, the compiler uses the `GroupBy` extension method from `IQueryable`.

When you run your program, the runtime will try to convert LINQ expressions to a SQL query. However, not all LINQ expressions can be converted to a SQL query, and therefore you get an exception.

However, if you are using an `IEnumerable`, the runtime will not generate a SQL expression. Instead, it will load all the items in memory and then apply your LINQ expressions on those collections.

Try changing to

```
var query = context.OrderItems.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.ItemOrdered.ProductType})
    .Select(y => new OrderItemReportDto
    {
        Name = y.Key.ProductType,
        Quantity = y.Sum(c => c.Quantity),
        Count = y.GroupBy(x => x.CreatedTime.Date).Select(x => x.Sum(c => c.Quantity)).ToArray()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Now, bear in mind that this is going to be an expensive operation since you will load all the items in memory and then apply the LINQ clauses. That means that all the fields/column, which you may not want will also be loaded in memory. If you are doing any filter operations using `Where`, you can try to do them before you convert the query to `IEnumerable`

I am using `ToList()` above because `ToListAsync()` is not available for `IEnumerable`.

If you do need to use async, you can do this

```
var query = context.OrderItems.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.ItemOrdered.ProductType})
    .Select(y => new OrderItemReportDto
    {
        Name = y.Key.ProductType,
        Quantity = y.Sum(c => c.Quantity),
        Count = y.GroupBy(x => x.CreatedTime.Date).Select(x => x.Sum(c => c.Quantity)).ToArray()
    }).AsQueryable()
    .ToListAsync();
```

However, I do not think that this `async` workaround will get you anything.

Comment: IEnumerable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and 
no accessible extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<OrderItemReportDto>' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I get this error. Is there any other answer you can suggest ? :)

Comment: @C.Cakir ToListAsync is not present for enumerable. However, you can use AsQueryable() on the end result if you do need to use an async list. (I have updated the answer)

Comment: Thank you Ankit. This Code Works Fine